# Converting and array

Tags: javascript

I have an arr like this

```
[{
    "ID": "this THE ID",
    "NAME": "this THE NAME",
    "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"
}, {
    "ID": "that ID",
    "NAME": "that THE NAME",
    "AGE": "that THE AGE"
}]
```

I'm looking to achieve this result:

```
[["this THE ID","this THE NAME","thiS THE AGE"], ["that ID","that THE NAME","that THE AGE"]]
```

What i tried

```
var result = []
data.forEach(function(ID,NAME,AGE) {
  result.push(ID)
  result.push(NAME)
  result.psuh(AGE)
});
```

But i am not getting the correct result that i wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map is your best friend in those kind of situation

```js
 var arr = [{
        "ID": "this THE ID",
        "NAME": "this THE NAME",
        "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"
    }, {
        "ID": "that ID",
        "NAME": "that THE NAME",
        "AGE": "that THE AGE"
    }]
 
 const result = arr.map(({ID,NAME,AGE}) => [ID,NAME,AGE]);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map the values, assuming you want the values in insertation order.

```js
var array = [{ ID: "this THE ID", NAME: "this THE NAME", AGE: "thiS THE AGE" }, { ID: "that ID", NAME: "that THE NAME", AGE: "that THE AGE" }],
    result = array.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

Your function need a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the properties and you could push an array with the values.

```js
var array = [{ ID: "this THE ID", NAME: "this THE NAME", AGE: "thiS THE AGE" }, { ID: "that ID", NAME: "that THE NAME", AGE: "that THE AGE" }],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function({ ID, NAME, AGE }) {
    result.push([ID, NAME, AGE]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You almost there:**

- You need to create a nested array for each iteration.
- You need to destructure the values as follow: `function({ID,NAME,AGE}){...}`

```js
var data = [{    "ID": "this THE ID",    "NAME": "this THE NAME",    "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"}, {    "ID": "that ID",    "NAME": "that THE NAME",    "AGE": "that THE AGE"}];

var result = []
data.forEach(function({ID,NAME,AGE}) {
  result.push([ID, NAME, AGE] /*Nested array*/);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using the function `map`:

```js
var data = [{    "ID": "this THE ID",    "NAME": "this THE NAME",    "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"}, {    "ID": "that ID",    "NAME": "that THE NAME",    "AGE": "that THE AGE"}];

var result = data.map(function({ID,NAME,AGE}) {
  return [ID, NAME, AGE];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

And the shortest, using `arrow function`:

```js
var data = [{    "ID": "this THE ID",    "NAME": "this THE NAME",    "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"}, {    "ID": "that ID",    "NAME": "that THE NAME",    "AGE": "that THE AGE"}];

var result = data.map(({ID,NAME,AGE}) => ([ID, NAME, AGE]));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you , your solution look close to mine

Answer (score 1):

You may do as follows;

```js
var arr = [{ "ID": "this THE ID",
             "NAME": "this THE NAME",
             "AGE": "thiS THE AGE"
           },
           { "ID": "that ID",
             "NAME": "that THE NAME",
             "AGE": "that THE AGE"
           }],
    brr = arr.map(Object.values);
 console.log(brr);
```